# Time-management software to create series of activities & notify what activity to do now?

Tags: windows, time-management

I'm looking for a software that enables me to create a series of activities. I set the period of each activity. When an activity ends, a notification window appears telling me to go to the next activity. Also I could set the number of loops of the whole series, which enables a series of activities to repeat multiple of times.

Also I can create and merge multiple series. Example: Set "*series 1*" to play with looping 3 times, then play "*series 2*" with looping 2 times, then "*series 3" with looping 2 times. And loop the mother series (containing both "*series 1*", "*series 2*", & "*series 3*") infinitely till I stop it.

**Simply**, we can consider that a countdown timer represents an activity. I'm looking for a software that enables me to play multiple countdown timers one after another.

The nearest software to what I'm looking for, according to my knowledge, is  [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/). Unfortunately, Workrave lacks the ability to create multiple activities (It has only two activities "*Micro-break*", and "*Rest break*"). Also it lacks the ability to run a series of activities (I can't tell the program to run 20 mins of work, then 5 mins of micro-break, then 20 mins of work, then 5 mins of micro-break, then 20 mins of work, then 10 mins of rest break, then repeat the whole series.

### Essential Features

- Ability to pause, or skip activity.

### Nice to have features

- Ability to create *auto-transitioning* activity guiding **slides** like what on Workrave. ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtgUR.png))
- **Activity log**: logs the time you've taken in each activity.
- Ability to set notification window **appearance period**.
- Ability to run activities in **parallel** (simultaneously): *play multiple activity series at the same time.*
- Ability to set customized **break periods** between specific activities.
- Ability to describe activities with styles (background colors, font styles, font colors, ... etc.) and text content (comment, description, title, ... etc.)

### Other Preferences

- Has to be a Windows desktop application (*Windows 8.1*)
- Price: Any

### Note

If you've a strong assumption that this app doesn't exist, so let me know in order to start programming such app.

Comment: Do you need this to be gratis or would you be willing to pay for it? (If so, how much?)

Comment: It's preferably be for free as I'm a student. If not, it's ok if it's around 15$. If more, I would try the program and think if the application worth the money, if it really worth, I could save for it.
So we can say the price option for this question is **ANY**